# Why some string operations work while others don't?

Tags: string, powershell, email

I'm working on a script which performs some distinctive actions, in order to keep track of the actions performed I'm storing some "logs" inside some variables and then doing a POST to a ticket with the actions done for each task. If at least one task fails I need to send an email to a team and notify them about this. As the ticketing tool and the email read this string differently I have to modify it so I'm calling a series of replace methods on the string.

The problem? The "runlog" isn't displayed correctly in the email body for some reason but only for 1 of the 3 tasks, the other 2 are correct.

This is not the actual script but a test scenario depicting what is happening:

```
$changeLog1 = "Failed to disable and/or move AD account\nFailed to remove all groups from AD account\nFailed to remove all groups and disable AD admin account\nFailed to disable AzureAD account\nFailed to disable AzureAD admin account\nFailed to remove extension attribute fie
lds in AD\nFailed to disable contact in USD\nUser has no devices in CMDB under his contact"

$changeLog2 = "Found CIs linked to user: \nSuccessfully used manager from AD\nFailed to send notification mail to manager"

$changeLog3 = "Failed to obtain all user aliases\nFailed to obtain all users from Kanban\nUser not found in Kanban\nFailed to disable the user in Kanban-STAID"

$emailLog = @()

$emailLog += "Processing change: $($openTicket.change_ref)\n\n"

$EmailLog += $changeLog1 + "\n\n"

$EmailLog += $changeLog2 + "\n\n"

$EmailLog += $changeLog3 + "\n\n"
```

I have a function which sends the email. And yes, I know Send-MailMessage is obsolete.. I'm trying to change that.

```
function sendMailSD {
    param ($log, $list)
    $smtp = ""
    $from = ""
    $to = ""
    $cc = ""
    $subject = "EmployeeOUT automation failed on $(Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy")"
    $body = "Hello all,

EmployeeOUT automation failed for the following changes:

$($list -join "`n")

The script run log file is the following

$(($log.replace("\n",".,") -replace ",","`n").replace("."," "))

Please assist with processing what automation failed to do.
Thank you!"

    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -cc $cc -Subject $subject -Body $body -Priority high
}
```

This sends the email with the following text for the runlog section:

```
Processing change:  
 
Failed to disable and/or move AD account Failed to remove all groups from AD account Failed to remove all groups and disable AD admin account Failed to disable AzureAD account Failed to disable AzureAD admin account Failed to remove extension attribute fields in AD Failed to disable contact in USD User has no devices in CMDB under his contact 
 
Found CIs linked to user:  
Successfully used manager from AD
Failed to send notification mail to manager 
 
Failed to obtain all user aliases
Failed to obtain all users from Kanban
Failed to disable the user in Kanban
Failed to disable the user in Kanban-STAID
```

I've been trying countless other ways of working with this string, I've tried changing `$emailLog` to be a simple variable and defining `$log = @()` with no luck. I've tried different combinations of `replace`, `join` and `split` with - or with .

I believe this would be a lot simpler if I create the email body in HTML but I'm just curious about what is going wrong here, if anyone has some ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show how you're calling your ```sendMailSd``` function with your sample data? If I try this: ```$(($emaillog.replace("\n",".,") -replace ",","`n").replace("."," "))``` I see the string split into multiple lines - is that what you're expecting to happen, but isn't? (Aside, I'm a bit confused by the use of multiple "replace" operations, but lets ignore that for a minute :-)).

Comment: If the email is sent as HTML, you'll ned to use `<BR>` elements instead of actual newlines (`"\`n"`)

Comment: I also see the string represented as it should if I only call that line, but when the e-mail is sent it's not like that ;[

sendMailSD $emailLog $failedTickets - this is how I call the function